# how to set jquery slider on auto instead of click or hover on thumbs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am new learner of jquery and javaScript.
i want to create a slider with a big image section and a section of thumbs.
slider should slide automatically i have coded so far is working on click or hover but i dont know how to set it on auto please help me how to modify my code. code and slider screen shoot is given below.
[slider image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKCi3.jpg)

```js
  $("document").ready(function()
   {
    
      $("#thumbs a").mouseenter(function()
    {
      var smallimgpath = $(this).attr("href");
   $("#bigimage img").fadeOut(function()
   {
   $("#bigimage img").attr("src",smallimgpath);
   $("#bigimage img").fadeIn();
   });
   return false;
   });
   
   });
   
    </script>
```

```css
#imagereplacement{
 
 border: 1px solid red;
 width:98%;
 height:400px;
 margin:auto;
 padding-top:8px;
 padding-left:10px;
}
#imagereplacement p{
 text-align:inline;
}
#bigimage{
 
 /* border: 1px solid green; */
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 float: left;
}
#thumbs{
 
 /*border: 1px solid yellow;*/
 margin: 110px 10px;
 text-align:center;
 width:29%;
 float: right;
}
#thumbs img{
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
}
```

```html
  //This is where all the JQuery code will go
   
 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="imagereplacement">
 <p id="bigimage">
 <a href="images/slider1.jpg"><img src="images/slider1.jpg"></a>
 </p>
 
 <p id="thumbs">
 <a href="images/slider1.jpg"><img src="images/slider1.jpg"></a>
 <a href="images/slider2.jpg"><img src="images/slider2.jpg"></a>
 <a href="images/slider3.jpg"><img src="images/slider3.jpg"></a>
 </p>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a software for slider like: https://amazingslider.com
you can make a beautiful slider. software gives you many options.

Comment: there are many ready made slider but my purpose is just to learn jquery.

Comment: make function slide() and put setTimeout(slide(),delay) at end of function before closing it, for smooth slide use setInterval

Comment: let me try, thanks for suggestion but where will i code this after which line of code ? can u explain more

Answer (score 0):

try with this example, please let me know in case of any more question from you :

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  var pages = $('#container li'),
    current = 0;
  var currentPage, nextPage;
  var timeoutID;
  var buttonClicked = 0;

  var handler1 = function() {
    buttonClicked = 1;
    $('#container .button').unbind('click');
    currentPage = pages.eq(current);
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevButton')) {
      if (current <= 0)
        current = pages.length - 1;
      else
        current = current - 1;
      nextPage = pages.eq(current);

      nextPage.css("marginLeft", -604);
      nextPage.show();
      nextPage.animate({
        marginLeft: 0
      }, 800, function() {
        currentPage.hide();
      });
      currentPage.animate({
        marginLeft: 604
      }, 800, function() {
        $('#container .button').bind('click', handler1);
      });
    } else {

      if (current >= pages.length - 1)
        current = 0;
      else
        current = current + 1;
      nextPage = pages.eq(current);

      nextPage.css("marginLeft", 604);
      nextPage.show();
      nextPage.animate({
        marginLeft: 0
      }, 800, function() {});
      currentPage.animate({
        marginLeft: -604
      }, 800, function() {
        currentPage.hide();
        $('#container .button').bind('click', handler1);
      });
    }
  }

  var handler2 = function() {
    if (buttonClicked == 0) {
      $('#container .button').unbind('click');
      currentPage = pages.eq(current);
      if (current >= pages.length - 1)
        current = 0;
      else
        current = current + 1;
      nextPage = pages.eq(current);
      nextPage.css("marginLeft", 604);
      nextPage.show();
      nextPage.animate({
        marginLeft: 0
      }, 800, function() {});
      currentPage.animate({
        marginLeft: -604
      }, 800, function() {
        currentPage.hide();
        $('#container .button').bind('click', handler1);
      });
      timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        handler2();
      }, 4000);
    }
  }

  $('#container .button').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    handler1();
  });

  timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
    handler2();
  }, 4000);

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 604px;
  height: 453px;
  position: relative;
}

#container .prevButton {
  height: 72px;
  width: 68px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('http://vietlandsoft.com/images/buttons.png') no-repeat;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-position: left top;
  left: 0
}

#container .prevButton:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
  left: 0;
}

#container .nextButton {
  height: 72px;
  width: 68px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('http://vietlandsoft.com/images/buttons.png') no-repeat;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0
}

#container .nextButton:hover {
  background-position: right bottom;
  right: 0;
}

#container ul {
  width: 604px;
  height: 453px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container li:first-child {
  display: list-item;
  position: absolute;
}

#container li {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <h1>HTML Slideshow AutoPlay (Slide Left/Slide Right)</h1>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="container">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://vietlandsoft.com/images/picture1.jpg" width="604" height="453" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://vietlandsoft.com/images/picture2.jpg" width="604" height="453" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://vietlandsoft.com/images/picture3.jpg" width="604" height="453" /></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="button prevButton"></span>
    <span class="button nextButton"></span>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: this example is awesome. thanks but 
what if i want to add thumbs along the slider if you have seen my uploaded pic.
and js code is too long to understand i need short code which would has easy to understand.

Comment: so please check the SetInterval() function :setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);

Comment: please check this example as well: https://css-tricks.com/examples/SimpleSlideshow/

Answer (score 0):

Here an example i've created that create an auto slider [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/CY5/pen/VagWmw) and [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ur717f6r/10/)

I've used an object literal pattern to create slide variable just to avoid creating many global function and variable. Inside document.ready i've initialised my slider just by calling slide.init({....}) this way it makes it easy to reuse and work like plugin.

```
$.extend(slide.config,option)
```

this code in simple words override you're default configuration defined in config key

as i mentioned in my above comment make a function slider() and place seTimeout(slide,1000) at bottom of your function before closing 
Here in this code its done in animate key of slide object it is passed with two parameter cnt and all image array, If cnt is greater then image array length then cnt is set to 0 i.e if at first when cnt keeps on increment i fadeout all image so when i make it 0 the next time the fadeToggle acts as switch

```
if On then Off  
if Off the On
```

and calling function slider after a delay makes it a recursive call its just one way for continuously looping there are many other ways i guess for looping continuous you can try

well i haven't check if all images Loaded or not which is most important in slider well that you could try on your own.

```js
var slide = {
  'config': {
    'container': $('#slideX'),
    'delay': 3000,
    'fade': 'fast',
    'easing': 'linear'
  },
  init: function(option) {
    $.extend(slide.config, option);
    var imag = slide.getImages();
    slide.animate(0, imag);
  },
  animate: function(cnt, imag) {
    if (cnt >= imag.length) {
      cnt = 0;
    }
    imag.eq(cnt).fadeToggle(slide.config.fade, slide.config.easing);
    setTimeout(function() {
      slide.animate(++cnt, imag);
    }, slide.config.delay);
  },
  getImages: function() {
    return slide.config.container.find('img');
  }
};



$(document).ready(function() {
  slide.init({
    'contianer': $('#slideX'),
    'delay': 3000,
    'fade': 'fast',
    'easing': 'swing'
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.contianer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.container > div,
.container > div >img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="slideX">
  <div id="img1">
    <img src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/magical-animal-photography-gregory-colbert/5.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="img2">
    <img src="http://cdn-5.webdesignmash.com/trial/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/great-dog-photography-016.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="img3">
    <img src="http://onlybackground.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/marble-beautiful-photography-1920x1200.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>
```